# ldap queries for an OU in knowing tree structure

Tags: linux, ldap, centos

I 'm trying 2 things in an tool called Itop on a Centos desktop.

I post here because it's about general ldap queries. I'm trying my queries with ldap explore and Itop.

1.import several users from an OU but it's not working.

My ldap query maybe isn't good:

```
(&(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(memberOf=CN=Organizational-Unit,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=local))
```

or

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=OU=Users,OU=Informatique,OU=Administration,DC=mydomain,DC=local))
```

knowing that my tree structure is like that:

```
DC=mydomain,DC=local => OU=Administration => OU=Informatique, OU=Users
```

2.import a specific user:

```
(objectcategory=user)((cn=seb))
```

The query is working but I have an error in Itop perhaps a field missed:
error:

```
An error occured while processing 1: Object not following integrity rules: issues = Unexpected value for attribute 'name': Null not allowed, Unexpected value for attribute 'email': Wrong format [seb@mydomain.local], class = Person, id =
```

How resolve that? with which queries?
Thanks,
seta

Comment: can you please paste what's info is entered for that specific user? Your error message says that the "Name" attribute is empty, and the email is in the wrong format. Where do you try to import this user? What's the LDAP server you're using?

Comment: For specific user, I launch only this query: `(objectcategory=user)((cn=seb))`

Comment: The tool Itop need to know a Name and an email. The name is seb and email is seb@mydomain.local. And for ohter query, I would like which one can list all users form OU=Users when you know my tree structure: `DC=mydomain,DC=local => OU=Administration => OU=Informatique, OU=Users`. The ldap server is an Active Directory and I 'm trying to do queries with linux and ldap explore.

Comment: Let me rephrase - you have some ldap class/object - called "user" that represents a user. This object/class has a schema - the schema tells all the attributes and object has. For example the schema for user could be - first/last name, email, password, etc. Can you please paste all those attributes (whatever they are - according to the schema you're using) for the user "sed".

Comment: okok In page where is showed errors, the requests fields are: `samaccountname => seb sn => empty - givenname => seb - userprincipalname => seb@mydomain.local - cn => seb - memberof => empty - mail => seb@mydomain.local - iTop Profiles => Portal user`and I don't know what add in my AD the fields 'sn' and 'memberof'

Comment: I fill in the fields email and sn in the Ad and it's working. But it isn't working to have the users list in the particular OU. Thanks for your contribution hovanessyan :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can try to help you with the query.  The (memberOf=*parameter*) filter is for groups, not OUs.  An LDAP query has three components: base, filter, and scope.  If you want all the users in your OU, then you need to set

1. base to the OU's distinguished name

   `OU=Users,OU=Informatique,OU=Administration,DC=mydomain,DC=local`
2. filter to get only users

   `(objectCategory=user)`
3. scope to Subtree (or OneLevel if you don't want to search the OU's underneath the target OU).

Comment: I do many research about ldap queries but I don't reach to adapt this command at my using. When I do:        `(&(objectclass=users)(OU=Users,OU=Informatique,OU=Administration,DC=mydomain,DC‌​=‌​local))` => nothing results I don't understand how get scope in the query. I reach with the ldp tool but the ldp query is: `ldap_search_s(ld,'OU=Users,OU=Informatique,OU=Administration,OU=mydomain,OU=loc‌​‌​al",1,"(objectclass=*)",attrList,0,&msg)`.    How translate this ldp query in ldap query?

Comment: @user1903539 You'll have to give more info on what API/tool you're using for your ldap query.  There is no such thing as "ldp query", that is an ldap query.

Comment: In fact, I use ldp from Windows server tools.  And also queries from Ad management tools (AD users and computers)

Comment: In ADUC, "base" is "Query root" and "scope" is the "Include subcontainers" checkbox.